# ActionView::MissingTemplate Error, Only When Visited By A Bot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionview

I have an action that serves my homepage. It works fine when visited normally (ie by a user in a web browser), but when visited by specific web crawlers, it throws the following error:

```
 A ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in tags#promoted:

 Missing template tags/promoted with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>["text/*"], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "/Apps/accounts/app/views", "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180@accounts/gems/devise-1.3.0/app/views"
 actionpack (3.0.4) lib/action_view/paths.rb:15:in `find'
```

It appears the bots are trying to fetch the `text/*` format, which there is no template for, which makes sense, so I tried to do the following in my action:

```
  def promoted
   request.format = :html #force html to avoid causing missing template errors
   # more action stuff....
  end
```

In essence, I am trying to force the request's format to html so it serves the html template.

Yet every time these set of bots request this page, the missing template error occurs.

It's not that big of deal, but ideally I'd like to resolve this error, if only so I stop getting these error emails from my app.

Is the only way to make a file called `my_action.text.erb` and put some gibberish in it? Or can I solve this more elegantly?

Comment: Can you post your controller code and specifically the 'index' action? This should be easy to untangle in a minute, to sort out Rail's auto-pilot of format serving.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been seeing these as well. You could use some middleware to rewrite these requests:

```
class Bot
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)
    h = env["HTTP_ACCEPT"]
    env["HTTP_ACCEPT"] = "text/html" if h == "text/*"
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

I forked a gem for killing off some MS Office Discovery Requests, and it seemed to make sense to add this middleware into it.

https://github.com/jwigal/rack-options-request

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this specific set of bots are as dumb as a rock, and ignore any sort of request formatting as I was trying to do. I ended up disallowing these bots' User-Agents in my `robots.txt`. No more errors. However, if somebody has a more elegant solution, please post it and I'll mark it as the accepted answer, otherwise, I'll accept this one in a couple of days.

Comment: Did you ever find a decent solution, the LinkedInBot is throwing these exceptions here.